# Is Acer Palmatum Diecious, Monoecious, or another variety of ecious?

Tags: trees, maple

I am compiling information about plants in my garden, and studying botany for interest, and was wondering if anyone knows whether Acer Palmatum (and more broadly Acers in general) are monoecious, diecious, etc.

I found some info stating that Acer Rubrum can be [either](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_rubrum#Description) [effectively](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2444057) but not sure for Acer Palmatum. I have not read the journal article yet admittedly, as I am looking for a way to access it that doesn't bust the bank.

Additionally, what is a good source for searching for this information, and other botanical info that might be slightly too niche or specific for general gardening practitioners?

Comment: I've never heard that Japanese Maples have male and female trees.
To discover this data on readily available nursery stock, look for the rare listing of Gingko, Holly, or Blackberries that tell you to order 1 male for a few female plants.

Comment: Dr. Michael Dirr has written an excellent reference, 'Manual of Woody Landscape Plants', now on its sixth edition, that should give you all the information you want on any landscape woody plant used in the US and Canada: https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/manual-of-woody-landscape-plants-michael-a-dirr/1101502925.  You can get earlier editions for much less money at used book sites.

Comment: That seems like an interesting book that might be worth picking up, even if it does not narrow down the specific answer in this case. I checked my Encyclopedias and could not find anything relevant in there relating to sex of plants, hence the question here.